# Getting different Buffers in Solana transactions. The front-end and back-end transactions are different

Tags: signature, typescript, instructions, error, transaction

I have a Solana dApp that requests tokens from a wallet that I own. When the user try to claim the Tokens, one transaction is created on the frontend and signed by the user; the signature is coded and sent to my backend API.
In my backend I have a function that verifies if the signature is valid: It mounts other transaction the same way (the same process) and verify if the client transaction and my generated transaction is the same. I used this script for more than 1 year but now Im getting so much trouble with differences in the Buffers of the instructions of my generated wallet:

Client instruction: TransactionInstruction {
keys: [
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(x)],
isSigner: false,
isWritable: true
},
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(y)],
isSigner: false,
isWritable: true
},
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(z)],
isSigner: true,
isWritable: false
}
],
programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)] {
_bn: <BN: (w) >
},
data: <Buffer 03 00 be 88 c6 1a 00 00 00>
}
generated instruction: TransactionInstruction {
keys: [
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(x)],
isSigner: false,
isWritable: true
},
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(y)],
isSigner: false,
isWritable: true
},
{
pubkey: [PublicKey [(z)],
isSigner: true,
isWritable: false
}
],
programId: PublicKey [PublicKey(TokenkegQfeZyiNwAJbNbGKPFXCWuBvf9Ss623VQ5DA)] {
_bn: <BN: (w) >
},
data: <Buffer 03 00 e4 0b 54 02 00 00 00>
}

I used x, y, z & w because this infos arent important (but they are the same on the transactions)

my problem is this Buffer, its different!:

<Buffer 03 00 e4 0b 54 02 00 00 00>

Im strugling with this problem like 1 week and I dont know what to to anymore.
This two transactions are made in the same process, using the same libs, functions, basicaly ctrl+c -> ctrl+v. And worked very well for an Year.

and is important to say that it still works with some wallets, but others is getting troubles

I code in Typescript, using Next.js and react for frontend and ts using Nest and Node.js in backend.

Comment: Which instruction are you trying to invoke on the Token Program specifically?

Comment: Token.createTransferInstruction() just the transfer instruction

Answer (score 1):

If the instruction you're using is created with  `createTransferInstruction()`, the `data` part of the instruction will contain the instruction key (which is `0x03` in both, so it's the same) and the amount of tokens.

The difference between your instructions is the amount of tokens, one of them is I think 10 tokens and the other 115 tokens.

Comment: How do you know the amount? how is made this Buffer?